# Find out the div id tag where widget drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a grid list and I wander how to find out the id of div tag where the widget droppable from jQuery drop!

As you can see in the code bellow I try with `jQuery(event.target)` to find out in witch div is dropping the object but is no working, I mean it's work but only sometimes, depends on the size of the div dropped! Any help will be good.

```
function elementDroppable( object ) {
    jQuery('.selectable').droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log( jQuery(event.target) );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try this:

    `function elementDroppable( object ) {
      jQuery('.selectable').droppable({
            var self = $(this);
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log( jQuery(self) );
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: It depends on how big the div is, if my div is 3 or 6 rows hight will give different result, I opened a new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260297/blocked-with-jquery-droppable-and-draggable-widgets