# Blocked with jQuery droppable and draggable widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I try to drag a `div` on a grids system rows, and to find out on witch rows he is positioned after is drop it:

https://jsfiddle.net/johnidevo/08f83op9/5/

```
________________________________________________
droppable_area_(grids)__________________________
1row____________________________________________
2row____________________________________________
3row___-----------------------------------------
4row___| draggable <div>                       |
5row___|                                       |
6row___-----------------------------------------
7row____________________________________________
(<div>'s)_______________________________________
```

My code is as follow:

```
jQuery( object ).draggable({                        
    snap: ".selectable",
    containment: "#droppable_area",
    axis: "y",
    drag: function( event, ui ){
        console.log( jQuery( this ).parent() );
    }
});

jQuery('.selectable').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log( jQuery( this ) );
    }
});
```

In Droppable function `console.log( jQuery( this ) );` *it give me some correct information but not always, why??*

***edit:***

With `console.log( jQuery( this ) );` when `draggable <div>` is only one row height size it's work fine, after if is bigger than 1 row size it's fails why?